# Wrapping a point cloud skeleton with a mesh

Tags: mesh

Using Unity I've been producing sculptural forms that look like this. It's made of patterns of cubes that twist around each other. I'm trying to get it into a 3D printable format.
[image]

From unity I export a PLY that is a list of the co-ords of each cube that looks like:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 17500
property float x
property float y
property float z
end_header
35 2.521441 0
34.72401 -2.06799 4.386663
33.90041 3.202552 8.704146
...
```

Then I've imported that into meshlab and run `Filters > Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction > Surface Reconstruction: Ball Pivoting` with the default parameters.

[image]

This is the result (different iteration so doesn't match top image but similar) which is ok, but obviously not 3d printable.

Is there a better way of doing this to either wrap around as if I were wrapping cling film (saran wrap) over the whole thing? Or to preserve the chains of cubes and print the skeleton?